# okhttp3 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect on HTTP Proxies

Tags: java, okhttp

i'm having this problem in a multi threaded application, the error doesn't seem to appear instantly but after i would guess 10k-15k requests, is there anything i can do to solve this error? for more info i'm also running proxies with authentication.

here's the stacktrace im getting;

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: no further information
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:116)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:266)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTunnel(RealConnection.kt:232)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:174)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:238)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:111)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:79)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:163)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:194)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:67)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

for threads i'm using ThreadPoolExecutor then using submit on a function where it does a simple okhttp3 request:

```
   Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://censored")
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.66 Safari/537.36")
                .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder().noCache().build());

   Response response = getClient().newCall(builder.build()).execute();
```

for proxies:

```
 final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
    builder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
    builder.connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = (route, response) -> {
            String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
            return response.request().newBuilder()
                    .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                    .build();
        };
    builder.proxy(proxy).proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator);
```

can anyone can help me with this? have been stuck on this for a few days and creating an issue on the okhttp3 repo they just told me to make a post here.

Comment: What version of OkHttpClient are you using? Do you close responses? Did you try to use a connection pool?

Comment: i'm using version: Version 5.0.0-alpha.10
no i do not close responses, didnt even know you could do that but i will give it a try.
no i have not tried and i wouldn't know how

Comment: i have just now tried to close all the requests after usage but that didn't help

Comment: i have also now just tried to use a connection pool like this:                 builder.proxy(proxy).proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator).connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(256,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
and that did not help still

Comment: This is wild. Like you're running out of outbound ports? How many total connections are opened? You can use OkHttp's EventListener for that.

Comment: i had already tried the eventlistener and i got this: https://pastebin.com/FLYRwVSy let me know if it helps

Comment: i have managed to solve the exception above by limiting the connections with setting the maxIdleConnections connectionPool to 100, however now i noticed a different exception which is not much as the one i posted which is: Required SETTINGS preface not received. what could i do to solve this?

Comment: That means your server isn't doing HTTP/2 properly.

Comment: well it's not my server, it's a popular website used by 400+ million people